# Reduce and Group a Hash with similar data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to group a hash in the following structure

```
{
  name: "cardio", 
  data: [["06:00", 999], ["09:00", 154], ["10:00", 1059], ["11:00", 90]]
}
{
  name: "swimming", 
  data: [["10:00",90 ], ["11:00", 50]]
}
```

Currently this is my data.

```
 [{"average_attendance"=>0.999e3, "sum_attendance"=>999, "place_type"=>"cardio", "rounded_hour"=>"06"},
{"average_attendance"=>0.154e3, "sum_attendance"=>154, "place_type"=>"cardio", "rounded_hour"=>"09"},
{"average_attendance"=>0.353e3, "sum_attendance"=>1059, "place_type"=>"cardio", "rounded_hour"=>"10"},
{"average_attendance"=>0.3e2, "sum_attendance"=>90, "place_type"=>"cardio", "rounded_hour"=>"11"},
{"average_attendance"=>0.45e2, "sum_attendance"=>90, "place_type"=>"swimming", "rounded_hour"=>"10"},
{"average_attendance"=>0.5e2, "sum_attendance"=>50, "place_type"=>"swimming", "rounded_hour"=>"11"}]
```

Is it possible to reduce and group it to build an array of [sum_attendance, rounded_hour] ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
> attendance_array.group_by{|e| e["place_type"]}.map{|k,v| {"name": k, "data": v.map{|r| [r["sum_attendance"],r["rounded_hour"]]}}}
# [
#   {
#       :name=>"cardio", 
#       :data=>[[999, "06"], [154, "09"], [1059, "10"], [90, "11"]]
#   }, 
#   {
#       :name=>"swimming", 
#       :data=>[[90, "10"], [50, "11"]]
#   }
# ]
```

First of all `group` it by `"place_type"` then prepare hash with `"name"` as group `key` and `"data"` as an array of `[sum_attendance, rounded_hour]`

Answer (score 1):

```
arr.each_with_object({}) do |g,h|
  k = g["place_type"]
  (h[k] ||= []) << ["#{g["rounded_hour"]}:00", g["sum_attendance"]]
end.map { |k,v| { name: k, data: v } }
  #=> [{:name=>"cardio", :data=>[["06:00", 999], ["09:00", 154],
  #                              ["10:00", 1059], ["11:00", 90]]},
  #    {:name=>"swimming", :data=>[["10:00", 90], ["11:00", 50]]}]
```

This could instead be written as follows.

```
arr.each_with_object(Hash.new { |h,k| h[k]=[] }) { |g,h|
  h[g["place_type"]] << ["#{g["rounded_hour"]}:00", g["sum_attendance"]] }.
    map { |k,v| { name: k, data: v } }
```

In my experience, the first method tends to be a bit faster.

In the second method

```
h = Hash.new { |h,k| h[k]=[] }
```

creates an empty hash, such that the block is executed if `h[k]` is invoked when `h` does not have a key `k`. Initially, the hash `h` is empty, so for any `k`, executing `h[k]` sets `h[k]` equal to an empty array. If we have

```
h[k] << 1
```

this results in

```
h[k] = h[k] << 1
  #=> [] << 1
  #=> [1]
```

If sometime later we have (for the same `k`)

```
h[k] << 2
```

we obtain

```
h[k] = h[k] << 2
  #=> [1] << 2
  #=> [1,2]
```

The block is not invoked this time, since `h` now has a key `k`. To be more precise about this, the method [Hash#[]](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-i-5B-5D) invokes the block when its argument is not a key of its receiver, `h`. `h[k]` on the left of the equality is the method [Hash#[]=](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-i-5B-5D-3D), which is why it does not also invoke the block.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
arr.each_with_object(Hash.new { |k, v| k[v] = {name: v, data: []} }) do |res, exp|
  exp[res["place_type"]][:data] << ["#{res["rounded_hour"]}:00", res["sum_attendance"]]
end.values

# [
#   {:name => "cardio", :data => [["06:00", 999], ["09:00", 154], ["10:00", 1059], ["11:00", 90]]},
#   {:name => "swimming", :data => [["10:00", 90], ["11:00", 50]]}
# ]
```